# How to change ouput of default Divi modules

Tags: wordpress, module, blogs, divi

I want to add/remove a few options from the existing Divi module.
For example in [Blog module](https://www.elegantthemes.com/documentation/divi/blog/) I want to add a custom field below the title of the post.
Please let me know how I can do it?

When I saw the code there is no hook available which I can use to add the custom fields.

So my question is that, How we can override output of the Divi module in child theme or by creating a plugin?

I tried following method: https://jonathanbossenger.com/building-your-own-divi-builder-modules/ which kind of works but the front visual builder is not loading and showing this error: https://prnt.sc/ue7csv

Comment: I tried following method: [https://jonathanbossenger.com/building-your-own-divi-builder-modules/](https://prnt.sc/ue7csv)
that kind of works but the front visual builder is not loading and showing this error:  [https://prnt.sc/ue7csv](https://prnt.sc/ue7csv)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please put relevant information into the question, not a comment. Please do not post text as images, copy-paste it. Read the [how-to-ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: Is my post published?

Comment: Yes, but as long as you do not fix your question, it is very unlikely that you'll get an answer that will actually help you.